# Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font-woff with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, fonts, font-awesome

I am getting `Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font-woff` warning in Chrome when I run my application. I understand that this is a common error & there are lots of post around the same issue.

I am using NodeJS and ExpressJS to run my web application and most of the solutions provided works for IIS or ASP.NET.

I looked at following links

1. [Link One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521130/google-warning-resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-appl)
2. [Link Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189089/google-chrome-gives-warning-resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mi)
3. [Link Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692674/resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-in-opencar)

The warning comes only in chrome broswer.

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font-woff: "data:font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAADV4ABMAAAAAVVAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA…0RofyBQ0TTUkwj7OhEtUMmyHSjGSOTuWY2rI32PdNJPiQZL3TSQq4+STRSagAAAAFVQS0vAAA=". jquery.js:1083
(anonymous function) jquery.js:1083
assert jquery.js:895
Sizzle.setDocument jquery.js:1082
(anonymous function) jquery.js:2556
(anonymous function) jquery.js:2611
(anonymous function) jquery.js:34
(anonymous function)
```

Please help.

Comment: `application/font-woff`

Comment: @idbehold: Where should I add this? I know the issue is due to missing `mime-type`. But with `NodeJs`, I dont know where I should add the `mime-type`?

Comment: it looks like you're creating them using data-uris, so: there. `data:application/font-woff;base64,.......`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Please add your comment as answer. You suggestion seems to be working for me & I will mark it as answer. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use full "type/encoding" mime type strings when using data-uris:

```
data:text/html;base64,.......
data:image/png;base64,.......
data:application/font-woff;base64,.......
```

In this case you're missing the "application" type indication.